# How to close an accordion tab when clicking another one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, accordion

I have this rather 'custom' accordion that allows me to add a class on the opened item (color).

But I'm still missing the mentioned feature: I want to auto-close all opened tabs except the one I'm clicking, so they don't pile up.

Here's my current code

**HTML**

```
<button class="accordion">Engagement Editor</button>
<div class="panel">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div><!-- /.end of job post -->

<button class="accordion">Partnership & Business Development Lead</button>
<div id="foo" class="panel">
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div><!-- /.end of job post -->

<button class="accordion">Assistant Video Editor</button>
<div id="foo" class="panel">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div><!-- /.end of job post -->
```

**JS**

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
    }
}
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qzkgjjzo/)**

Comment: This is already how jquery-ui accordion works, just make sure your mark up looks like theirs https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qzkgjjzo/4/)**

You remove `active` class from all the `.accordion` buttons when you click then active the clicked one :

```
$('.accordion').removeClass('active');
```

Also remove the `show` class from all the panels then add it to the consirned one :

```
$('.panel').removeClass('show');
```

**NOTE :** It will be better to put the function out of the loop (e.g `click_action()`) then just call it inside.

You could also take a look to the full jQuery solution **[Fiddle HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/qzkgjjzo/5/)**.

Hope this helps.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

function click_action(){
  $('.accordion').removeClass('active');
  $('.panel').removeClass('show');

  this.classList.toggle("active");
  this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
}

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = click_action;
}
```

```css
button.accordion {
  background-color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0px 0 8px 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
  color: #f06100
}

button.accordion:before {
  content: '\02795';
  font-size: 9px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 7px;
}

button.accordion.active:before {
  content: "\2796";
}

div.panel {
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  padding-left: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 0px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #ccc;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.panel-icon {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.panel h5 {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 23px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #2d2d2d
}

.panel p {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 23px;
  padding: 15px 30px 20px 0;
  color: #2d2d2d
}

div.panel.show {
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="accordion">Engagement Editor</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div><!-- /.end of job post -->

<button class="accordion">Partnership & Business Development Lead</button>
<div id="foo" class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div><!-- /.end of job post -->

<button class="accordion">Assistant Video Editor</button>
<div id="foo" class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div><!-- /.end of job post -->
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick.

Could I close the active tab onClick?

Comment: You're welcome, glad i could helps... since you're using jquery i suggest this **[Full jQuery solution](http://jsfiddle.net/qzkgjjzo/5/)** (answer close also the active tab onclick question)

Answer (score 0):

First, [don't create functions in loops](http://tobyho.com/2011/11/16/7-common-js-mistakes-or-confusions/).

Second, why are you using jQuery & jQuery UI if you're intending to use vanilla DOM APIs like `classList` and `getElementsByClassName`?

Third, if you wish to fix the vanilla JavaScript solution you made in your JSFiddle, here is some code that works:

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var panels = document.getElementsByClassName("panel");
var i;
var j;

var handleAccordionClick = function(){
    for(j = 0; j < panels.length; j++){
        acc[j].classList.remove("active");
        panels[j].classList.remove("show");
    }
    this.classList.add("active");
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.add("show");
}

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = handleAccordionClick;    
}
```

Bear in mind that this is not efficient. It sets all the accordions to an inactive state, then sets the clicked accordion to active. For a better solution, invest more time in a more efficient vanilla solution or, if you intend to use jQuery, look into `.siblings()`